# Transition Drawable for actionbar in Android

Tags: android, transitiondrawable

Is it possible to use transition drawable for Actionbar and how? 
I should use an xml like:

```
 <xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"/>
 <transition xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"/>
 <item android:drawable="@drawable/first_image"/>
 <item android:drawable="@drawable/second_image"/>
 </transition>
```

but how I continue from here?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible.
You can do it without XML, just create a `TransitionDrawable` in your code:

```
Drawable firstImage = getDrawable(R.drawable.first_image);
Drawable secondImage = getDrawable(R.drawable.secondImage);
TransitionDrawable transition = new TransitionDrawable(new Drawable[] {
        firstImage, secondImage});
```

After that set this transition as background to your ActionBar:

```
getSupportActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(transition);
```

And start the transition:

```
transition.startTransition(1000);
```

Also you can set this transition as background to Toolbar.